# total number of matching 2 different column in excel

Tags: excel

Excel Sheet 1

| Date | Application | Severity | Progress % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/10/2022 | Mobile App | Urgent | 10% |
| 1/10/2022 | Mobile App | High | 0% |
| 1/10/2022 | Mobile App | Urgent | 0% |
| 1/10/2022 | Web App | Low | 100% |
| 1/10/2022 | Web App | Low | 100% |
| 2/10/2022 | Mobile App | Urgent | 10% |
| 2/10/2022 | Web App | Low | 100% |

Excel Sheet 2

to find out how many total no of severity for the application and get same progress from sheet 1

| Application | Severity | Total no of Issue | Progress % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mobile App | Urgent | ? | ? |
|  | High | ? | ? |
|  | Medium | ? | ? |
|  | Low | ? | ? |
| Web App | Urgent | ? | ? |
|  | High | ? | ? |
|  | Medium | ? | ? |
|  | Low | ? | ? |

what formula to use?

Comment: Have you considered or tried sumifs() or countifs() and how will you combine the %? or take the max or the average or weighted average?

Comment: Did you try a pivot table?

Comment: You should add expected output, specially about how to calculate Progress % because there are different ways of doing it, but this case sounds like you may benefit from Pivot Tables

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it using the COUNTIFS and SUMPRODUCT with multiple criterias.

- At I column, count the number of items that match with Application (G column) and Severity (H column)

  =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8;$G$2;$C$2:$C$8;H2)
- At J column, sum the items that match with Application (G column) and Severity (H column)

  =IFERROR((SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8=$G$6)*($C$2:$C$8=H9);$D$2:$D$8)*100)/I9;0)

[image]

Comment: Is summing the completed percentage correct?